# How to play RTMP stream in html once it's available?

Tags: javascript, html, rtmp, amazon-ivs

We have an RTMP stream from AWS IVS.

We are playing the RTMP stream in an HTML page using the following code from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/player-web.html):

```
if (IVSPlayer.isPlayerSupported) {
    const player = IVSPlayer.create();
    player.attachHTMLVideoElement(document.getElementById('video-player'));
    player.load(PLAYBACKURL);
    player.play();
}
```

This code works only when the RTMP stream is already playing. If the stream from IVS is not ready when the html page is loaded, then the video is not played when it's ready. Hence the end user has to keep running this code (using a button for example)...

The ideal solution would be: when the RTMP stream is ready, play the video without the need of refreshing the page or running this code again.

How can I solve that?

Comment: See [Amazon IVS Player docs](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.6.1/web/), especially for [`Player.load()`](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.6.1/web/interfaces/player.html#load) and [`Player.play()`](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.6.1/web/interfaces/player.html#play), regarding what they have to say about `PlayState`.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for your comment. I came across this page but I couldn't find any example about the syntax of these events/functions. Do you have any idea please ? Thanks

Comment: Use [`Player.addEventListener()`](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.6.1/web/interfaces/player.html#addeventlistener) to set listeners for events, especially [`PlayerState`](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.6.1/web/index.html#playerstate) events.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something about playing RTMP in H5, it's about H5 `<video>` playing HLS, which is coverted by AWS IVS, because now H5 is not able to play RTMP.